# Insert two values in temp table from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I insert different values from two different tables into temp table in SQL?

I want to have combination of all timeid values from today(from 00-24 h), and to have also all product types from other table combined with timeid.

So far I have only

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTableDay(TimeId INT, ProductType NVARCHAR(100),NetIncomeByProduct INT)
            INSERT INTO #TempTableDay(TimeId,ProductType)
            SELECT Id AS TimeId
            FROM DimTime DT
            CROSS APPLY [GetDayIdFromTimeIdTab](Id) FDD  
            WHERE FDD.DayId = @CurrentSelectedPeriod
```

My second table is DimProductType, where I have ProductTypeId.

Comment: Your question is unclear here. You need to try to explain your goal more. Some sample data and expected results would likely help greatly.

Comment: I already solved this issue. CROSS JOIN helped me